# Why am I getting this error after angular cli update

Tags: angular, angular6

Updated to latest angular and getting following error when I run `ng serve`. I couldn't understand what would be the issue.

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "F:\\angular\\July\\FinalTest".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "F:\\angular\\July\\FinalTest".

    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\archit
ect\src\architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
    at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:
45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75
:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:
14)
```

`ng -v` command display

```
    Angular CLI: 6.1.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------

@angular-devkit/architect       0.7.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            0.7.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      0.7.1 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    <error>
@angular/compiler-cli           <error>
@angular/language-service       <error>
@schematics/angular             0.7.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/update              0.7.1 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.2.2
typescript                      2.7.2 (cli-only)
```

How could I fix this. Please help me someone

Comment: Try `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular`. See also related https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10661

Comment: @Igor still same issue

Comment: Did you read the other comments from the github ticket (see link in previous comment). There are other proposed solutions that might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to install devDependencies with "save-dev" and the same for dependencies.

`npm i --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli`

Finally finish up with `npm install` and `npm update`.